# i created one lambda for capturing event REMOVE but now i want to add that deleted record to another table (AWS dynamo)

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

created this function

```
function captureDeletedRecord(event, context, callback) {
 logger.log('captureDeletedRecord() called with event: ', event);
 config.load(context);

 event.Records.forEach((record) => {
 console.log('Stream record: ', JSON.stringify(record, null, 2));

if (record.eventName == 'REMOVE') {

}
```

I am having 2 tables if I deleted the record from Table1 then that record needs to be added in table2.
applied trigger on table1:

```
"msg": "[LOG] captureDeletedRecord() called with event: ",
    "payload": {
        "Records": [
            {
                "eventID": "5668d87327832814",
                "eventName": "REMOVE",
            "eventVersion": "1.1",
            "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
            "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
            "dynamodb": {
                "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1619594603,
                "Keys": "****<REDACTED>****",
                "SequenceNumber": "21322323",
                "SizeBytes": 8,
                "StreamViewType": "NEW_IMAGE"
            },
```

now i want to add deleted record from table1 to table 2,
can anyone help n this?